# FancyBox & ImageLens

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm trying to load an image using FancyBox and once the image is loaded it should display a magnifying glass when hovering over the image.

I'm using the following javascript file to display the magnifying glass:
http://www.dailycoding.com/Uploads/2011/03/imageLens/demo.html

My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
/* This is basic - uses default settings */
$("a#single_image").fancybox({

    'titlePosition' : 'inside',
      onComplete: function(){
        alert("test");
                $("#fancybox-img").imageLens();
       }


    });
```

I'm trying to load the imageLens using the "onComplete" method but nothing happens... does anyone know whats wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, but no magnifying glass..

Comment: There is some FancyBox and lense CSS properties conflict. There is magnifying glass actually you just can't see it.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Do you know a solution for this? Or perhaps a different maginfying glass I could use?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Colorbox plugin (it's similar to fancybox):

```
$(".callbacks").colorbox({
  onComplete:function(){$('.cboxPhoto').imageLens( {lensSize: 200 });  }
});
```